# Assign Button id to a variable using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

i tried getting the button id, setting it as a variable and set it as inner element of a paragraph tag. but it is failing, im not sure where i messed up the process.

here is what i have done so far.

dont worry about the innerhtml being wrong, it works when i replace it with string texts. i just removed the rest so its clearer

let me know if im missing some key information. ill edit it right away

```
<script>
function ViewDetail(clicked_id) {
          let btnid = obj.id;
          document.getElementById("outme").innerHTML = btnid;
        }
</script>
```

```
<a href="view.php?id=<?=$rows['id']?>" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="ViewDetail(this.id)" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">View</a>

        <div class="modal-body">
            <p id='outme'>default id</p>
        </div>
```

Comment: You are not defining any `id` on the `a` tag

Comment: `clicked_id` is already the `id`. Also, you haven't defined `obj`.

Comment: ok thank you for the feedbacks. i will take a look

Comment: i have changed line 4 of first javascript code to this but its still not echoing the button id
document.getElementById("outme").innerHTML = clicked_id;

Comment: There is no `id="sssss"` on the link.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have added Id attributes in button:

```
 <script>
    function ViewDetail(btnid) {
              let btnid = obj.id;
              document.getElementById("outme").innerHTML = btnid;
            }
    </script>
```

Added Id attributes:

```
<a id="<?=$rows['id']?>" href="view.php?id=<?=$rows['id']?>" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="ViewDetail(this.id)" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">View</a>

        <div class="modal-body">
            <p id='outme'>default id</p>
        </div>
```

Comment: it works very well. the parts i needed to learn was easy to spot .
thank you very much